# lme4: Why the random-effects summary correlation between intercept and time-factor not equal correlation of conditional modes from "ranef" and "coef"?

Tags: correlation, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), subset(sleepstudy,Days<=5))
g<-as.data.frame(ranef(fm1))
cor(g[1:18,]$condval,g[19:36,]$condval)
```

[1] -0.07753203

```
summary(fm1)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
   Data: subset(sleepstudy, Days <= 5)

REML criterion at convergence: 994.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4726 -0.5462  0.0644  0.5054  2.3481 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 Subject  (Intercept) 743.78   27.272        
          Days         75.72    8.702   -0.20
 Residual             310.89   17.632        
Number of obs: 108, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  252.819      7.097  35.623
Days           9.984      2.279   4.381

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Days -0.315
cor(coef(fm1)[["Subject"]][["(Intercept)"]],coef(fm1)[["Subject"]][["Days"]])


-0.07753203
```

Why is the lme4 summary -.2 while correlation gives me -.07?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number is the observed correlation between the parameter estimates for the 18 subjects in the dataset. The second number is the [restricted maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_maximum_likelihood) estimate of the "true" correlation in the population. Because of measurement error, observed correlations are generally weaker than the corresponding true correlations.

Comment: Also it's like saying you have a sample of values and when you calculate the sample correlation it doesn't match the population correlation: that's expected.